# Robot model not showing in rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to work with this repository: https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Kinematics-Project

I did all the initial steps that are mentioned in the repo but have troubles showing the robot urdf in rviz. Since the people over there can't help I hope that someone here can point me in the right direction.

When I just want to load the urdf in rviz like this (in individual shells):

```
roscore
rosrun rviz rviz
roslaunch kuka_arm load_urdf.launch
```

I just see the gripper. You can see this in the first photo attached.

The urdf to me looks fine and there are no errors anywhere.

When I run the whole demo, like this:

`rosrun kuka_arm safe_spawner.sh`

I can verify that the model is correctly loaded in gazebo as you can see in the second screenshot.
I tried this on two computers, one in a VM, one natively and with integrated graphics and dedicated nvidia card.

Can anyone else please check the urdf and help me out in determining what the problem here is?

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266313/robot-model-not-showing-in-rviz/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2017-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-13**:
Do you have the robot description on the VM? Which computer is not showing the model?

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2017-07-13**:
I set up everything like it says in the readme on both. And it is not showing on either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some rviz users have encountered a similar issue on newer ubuntu/debian versions e.g. ROS Lunar on Ubuntu Artful or ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Bionic (see for example: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1249). The issue may be related to your locales.

If that's the underlying issue, modifying the following environment variable will fix it for you:

`export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [diogoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/30827/diogoa/) on 2019-01-04**:
This was a lifesaver, thank you!